# I already have python 2.7 install plus 3.6 install but when I try to install Django it give me the following error

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip

```
The directory '/Users/sandeepkrishnan/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/sandeepkrishnan/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: django in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. This right here tells you that `django` is already installed into Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You're installing Django into Python 2.7 instead of 3.6, but you already have it installed in 2.7. To install it in Python 3.6, try `pip3 install django` and see if that works.